# silex and twig css cache issues - odd behavior

Tags: css, google-chrome, twig, phpstorm, silex

I've run into a very frustrating bug. I can't reload changes in my css file.

style.css seen in PhpStorm looks like:

```
body {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Yet seen in Chrome shows:

```
body {
  background-color: green;
}
```

Here's the odd behaviour: If I change style.css to "foo bar testing"

Chrome displays it as:

```
body {
  backgrou
```

And also, if I dump a lot of arbitary text into style.css, Chrome displays it as:

```
body {
  background-color: green;
}
���������������������������������������������������������������...etc
```

So Chrome recognizes that it's changed, but is fixed with the original text.

My twig options are:

```
$app['twig.options'] = array('cache' => false, 'auto_reload' => true);
```

I've also tried appending `?{{ random() }}` to style.css in a effort to force reloading with no joy.

Comment: How do you include the CSS? The twig `cache` does not cache the CSS files.. It only converts the twig templates to their PHP relevant code

Comment: css is included in my base twig template:  <link href="/css/style.css?{{random()}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Comment: What happens when you do a hard refresh? (`CTRL`+`F5`)

Comment: Hard refresh, incognito mode, change of browser & clearing browser cache has the same behaviour. The file within a browser clearly shows a change of text amount, so I've ruled out browser cache issues.

Comment: Is this on a local test server or a live server? Perhaps the server has a caching system which is preventing CSS changes to be reflected directly. I'm most certain this is not due to using silex and twig though

Comment: I'm using Vagrant / Nginx to host the site - it seems like you're correct! I've made a dummy test.css in nano and the same behaviour exists. I'll explore Nginx as the culprit. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue is with running Nginx withing VirtualBox.

in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` sendfile needs to be off